Full HTML not loading for PlayWrightFetcher
I'm trying to scrape video URLs given a list of TikTok usernames. To start, I'm trying just to get the html from https://www.tiktok.com/@therock. When I inspect element, I can see the Tiktok video URLs, but when I run this code, I get pretty much everything except that section.
Here is my code:
page = await PlayWrightFetcher.async_fetch('https://www.tiktok.com/@therock', headless=True, disable_resources=False, real_chrome=True)

print(page)

Here's a chunk of what I see when I inspect element (and what I don't see in the code):
DivItemContainerV2e19c29qe17"><div data-e2e="user-post-item" overflow="hidden" class="css-8dx572-DivContainer-StyledDivContainerV2 eq741c50" tabindex="0" role="button" aria-label="Watch in full screen"><div style="padding-top: 132.653%;"><div class=" css-13fa1gi-DivWrapper e1cg0wnj1"><a href="https://www.tiktok.com/@therock/video/7452740726187642155" tabindex="-1"

In my current output, I'm getting the following in the section where I expect to see video URLs:
e15jf4tc0"></div><div class="css-14axsae-DivSkeletonCard e15jf4tc0"></div><div class="css-14axsae-DivSkeletonCard e15jf4tc0"></div><div class="css-14axsae-DivSkeletonCard


What language is this? PlayWrightFetcher.async_fetch isn't part of any PW API I'm familiar with, so if you are using Python, i suggest showing how you wound up building that object (a [mcve]). Please tag with a top-level language.
